# Microsoft .NET SOAP "Web Services Security 3 UsernameToken Profile" implemtation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a client that has a SOAP Web Service implemented using .NET. I have been working on setting up our application to communicate with their Web Service.

My question is related to the authentication mechanism they use. They use the UsernameToken Profile authentication. This type of authentication supports two types of password, PasswordText and PasswordDigest.

From the [Standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf) I understand that the Nounce and Created headers should only be sent if the PasswordDigest type is used, if you use the PasswordText type, they are not needed. Also, the [Standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf) specifies that the Nounce and Created are optional parameters in PasswordDigest type.

Can anyone confirm that, if the PasswordText option is used, the Nounce and Created headers are not used in the .Net implementation ?

I tried to search on the ASP projects but couldn't find the implementation. I don't know if (Microsoft.Web.Services3) is open source.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just need to be clear. The token is username with password?how many textboxes the token has?

Comment: Yes, you need a username and a password or digest_password. That do you mean by textboxes ?

Comment: Never mind textboxes, what i mean is the parameter. How many parameter does your web service has?

Comment: @reds What parameters ? The WS operation ? The authentication mechanism ? If you refer to the auth, I can provide the Username and Password and it works. But the client (WS owner) asks me to add the Nounce and Created field.

Comment: i can create microsoft .net WS, but dont know what you mean by Nounce and Created field. sorry

Answer (score 0):

To Communicate with  Microsoft .Net Web Service, as long as the WS is deployed and running, For .Net Developers We can use the WS "End Point". This means when you run the WS in a browser it means the "link" of .asmx file.

Wethier Port Forwarding changed the IP or not.

To Execute the WS in IIS itself or any, right click .asmx file ==> Browse

**Token?**
Depends on the function created by the WS,it maybe 1 or more.. or nothing It depends on the project developers.

**Connectivity?**
Depends if the WS is publicly accessible or not.

Just adding more info to help.